# Using Zombies in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Zombies to try and get rid of an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

In Zombies, I got this message when the app crashes -

> An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at
>   address: 0x8955310.

My question is what do I do next to solve the problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable NSZombie in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)

Comment: The question is not clear. `what do I do next to solve the problem` can be interpreted in a variety of ways. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn on malloc stack logging and zombies for your scheme in Xcode, and run the app in the simulator.  Xcode should enter the debugger when the message is sent to the zombie.  Run this command at the debugger prompt:

```
info malloc 0x8955310
```

(Substitute the actual address of the zombie!)  You'll get stack traces from when that address was allocated and freed.

Comment: I've got a really stupid question - where exactly do i run the command malloc_history PID 0xADDRESS | less. in the terminal ?

Comment: I have changed my answer to use gdb's built-in malloc history support.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have created an object, released it and later sent it a message.

To make sure this won't happen, a safe practice would be to set your object to `nil` once you are done using it

Consider:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSmutableArray array];
[a dealloc];
[a do_something_weird];
```

Your app is likely crash (won't always crash) in response to this message, as after release, you don't own this memory, and it may be used by some other object.

If you change this sequence to

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSmutableArray array];
[a dealloc];
a=nil;
[a do_something_weird];
```

Exactly nothing will happen. This is a safe practice to follow when you are sure you're done using the object.

You also may want to consider using the [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) feature, which helps a lot with memory management.

Comment: Hi @JAM, I think he is asking how to get the object(whose address is 0x8955310) in code that met this issue. :)

Comment: I suppose "what do I do next to solve the problem" can be interpreted in a more then one way :)

Comment: Aha, you're right, and I'm sure your answer is the solution after got the object. :D