# iphone application crash on replacing the video files

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, unrecognized-selector

I only replace the video files in my existing code, but if i replace all the video files my application will crash in iphone. it is an universal application but Ipad support all the new video files and crash on iphone. the following warning occur:

> [**NSCFType setLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x19d790 2012-02-29 15:13:49.932[584:307] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType
>   setLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19d790'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation                      0x3759dc7b __exceptionPreprocess + 114  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x32d9bee8 objc_exception_throw + 40  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x3759f3e3 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 98   3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x37544467 __*forwarding*** + 506
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x37544220
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48    5   Visionaries                         0x00005179 -[Visionaries_ViewController
>   connection:didReceiveResponse:] + 56  6   Foundation
>   0x35183cd5 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal)
>   sendDidReceiveResponse:] + 92     7   Foundation
>   0x35183c3b _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveResponse + 86    8   CFNetwork
>   0x302941b4
>   _ZN19URLConnectionClient29_clientSendDidReceiveResponseEP14_CFURLResponsePNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE
>   + 64  9   CFNetwork                           0x30284bc8 _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl
>   + 332     10  CFNetwork                           0x30284d84 _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl
>   + 776     11  CFNetwork                           0x30284984 _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 100  12  CFNetwork                           0x3028484c _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 192   13  CFNetwork
>   0x30284788 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 12    14  CoreFoundation
>   0x375518d1 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 14  15  CoreFoundation                      0x37521ecd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 384  16  CoreFoundation                      0x375216f9 __CFRunLoopRun + 264     17  CoreFoundation
>   0x3752150b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 226     18  CoreFoundation
>   0x37521419 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 60    19  GraphicsServices
>   0x33e76d24 GSEventRunModal + 196  20  UIKit
>   0x3591d57c -[UIApplication _run] + 588    21  UIKit
>   0x3591a558 UIApplicationMain + 972    22  Visionaries
>   0x00002391 main + 80  23  Visionaries
>   0x0000233c start + 40 ) terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException'

Somebody has an idea, please help.

Comment: Provide more information about what you are doing with those videos. What does your app do? What do you mean replace the video files in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the crash log we see that, inside -[Visionaries_ViewController connection:didReceiveResponse:], you are calling the method setLength: on an object that does not have that method.

Can be a memory or logic problem. Please provide more info.

Comment: But the same will work with iPhone 3GS and iPad1 also, the crash with only iPhone 3G.But if i use another mp4 files the same code will work with iPhone 3G also. I am unable to find the problem with new mp4 files. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Seems like a memory problem. Try using Instruments and Zombies.

Comment: Thanks for reply fbernardo, will you please share the process of using instruments and Zombies.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8276376/366492 for zombies and check the apple documentation for Instruments, it's a complex tool. I recommend the WWDC videos (wwdc 2010 had a great session on the subject).

Comment: Thanks for reply. the problem is removed, when i change the type of audio files from .mp4 to .m4v